# How to create crawelable Ajax using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, seo

I am going to create a crawelable ajax by jquery, How to do it? before I had a website that used jquery Ajax for searching my website but nothing indexed.

this is the new way tha I use:

```
<a href="www.example.com/page1" id="linkA">page 1</a>
```

And then show result by ajax and don't allow the link to go:

*javascript*

```
    $("body").on("click","#linkA",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href=$(this).attr('href');

   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"ajax/return.php",
    data:({page:href}),
    success:function(data){
        $("body").html(data);
    }

   }) 
});
```

my questions:

1- Is the way that I am using true?

2- Is this way crawelable?

Comment: _crawelable_? Perhaps you meant **indexable**?

Comment: If you meant that the results fetched are crawlable by search engine bots .. then `NO` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way that you are using is true, and it's a good way, but google has an article about **[Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)**

Answer (score 0):

As long as the links you provide in the "href" attribute are also rendered correctly by the server if the browser accesses them directly, you're on the safe site. You should also use HTML5 History API and Pushstate in order to reflect the url of the page currently shown, so visitors can use their browser history buttons, send links to pages and favorize them in their browser.

Google and the other search engines normaly won't execute your javascript and try directly to access the links you provide.

If your site got heavy scripts to load or static parts like header, footer, menu it's a great way to improve your loading / rendering speed by hijacking the links and loading only the needed content via javascript.